# Codename One Barcode Scanner Fails to Return Value

Tags: java, codenameone, barcode

My application returns unsupported using the cn1-codescan.cn1lib. When I use the deprecated CodeScanner (com.codename1.codescan.*) the scanner application works but a value is never returned. I'm testing on a Samsung Note 4, in case that might make a difference...

```
private void scanIt(TextField tfField)
{
    if(CodeScanner.isSupported())
    {
        CodeScanner cs = CodeScanner.getInstance();
        if(cs != null)
        {
            MyScanResult msr = new MyScanResult();
            cs.scanBarCode(msr);
            tfField.setText(msr.scancode);
        }
        else
            tfField.setText("No Instance!");
    }
    else
        tfField.setText("Not Supported!");
}

import com.codename1.ext.codescan.*;

public class MyScanResult implements ScanResult
{
    public String scancode = null;

    public MyScanResult()
    {      
    }

    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes)
    {
        scancode = contents;
    }

    public void scanCanceled()
    {
        scancode = "Canceled";
    }

    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message)
    {
        scancode = "Error! "+message;
    }            
}
```

These are the two relevant function calls. I appreciate your help in advance. Thank-you.

Comment: Added the codenameone tag which is crucial in this case as this is a Codename One question.

Answer (score 0):

When using a deprecated API you can point your IDE on the deprecated feature to get additional help and in most cases the deprecation is explained and the class you should use is mentioned in the deprecation notice.

You specifically used `com.codename1.codescan.CodeScanner` which is the old no longer working implementation. You should have used `com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner` which isn't deprecated and should work fine. It will be there only if the cn1lib is installed and refreshed.

Comment: I get 'not supported' when I do as you suggest. CodeScanner.isSupported() returns false. I am using NetBeans 11.2, If that could make a difference...

Comment: I am using cn1-codescan.cn1lib and the libraries have been refreshed. I only mentioned the deprecated routine because is comes closer to working.

Comment: That's pretty odd. If you're running on an Android device supported should always return true and succeed. I don't see a case where it should fail at this stage assuming you are using the `ext` package. Can you connect the device with a cable and see what's printed to logcat when you run the program. I'm guessing there's an exception there.

Comment: I am using adb logcat to try to locate an error, since no matter what I do this code fails and comes back not supported. I need to get this behind me but I'm stumped. What can I do to nail down this issue? I can see where the code hits my tag - Log.p(TAG, Log.DEBUG); which I added but there appears to be no errors in the log.

Comment: Which codescanner app are you using?
Have you tried using the LittleMonkey code scanner cn1lib? It might provide a smoother experience for your case

Comment: I added QRScanner.cn1lib to the lib folder and then I used the option 'refresh cn1lib files' (I am using NetBeans 11.2). The library refuses to load. The import I had to put in manually is "import org.littlemonkey.qrscanner.*;" but org is underlined and the ide cannot find the library. Is there any other thing I can do to load the library?

Comment: I also notice that a .ver file in the lib folder is not created unlike other cn1libs that are loaded.

Comment: Check that the cn1lib file is a valid zip file, if not the download is corrupted delete it and try downloading again

Comment: I just tried CodeNameSettings again and this time I got the file properly and it works! I'll try my code again. I'm baffled as to what the issue was.

Comment: OK, getting close. Now I get a scan error 404 Scanner not Supported I'll check logcat now and see if there's any clues there.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get past this?

Comment: I have Barcode Scanner + loaded on the phone. Should that application work with QRScanner?

Comment: Try this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en_US